# UWP TimePicker Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, visual-studio-2017, timepicker

I am currently working on an app that uses the tool "TimePicker" in Blend for Visual Studio 2017 and I have a question regarding an event I'm trying to find. After a time is selected I wish to have separate events to occur when check-button is pressed that changes the time and if the X-button is pressed to cancel and return from the flyout. I do believe I can use the TimePicker's TimeChanged event to tell whether or not the check button was pressed but I cannot figure out which event would work for if the x-button to cancel was pressed. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no obvious way to do it. There's a Dismiss button in the `TimePickerFlyoutPresenter`, but getting access to that is not enough. You'll also need to manage keyboard shortcuts, like the [ESC] key.

You got me a bit curious on how to hack it, so here's what I've come up with so far. Here's a `TimePickerDismissal` class I hacked-up real quick. The idea is if the `TimePicker` gains focus after it pushed a popup and it did not report a time change, then it's considered a dismiss.

```
public class TimePickerDismissal
{
    private bool _active;
    private bool _timeChanged;

    public event EventHandler Dismissed;

    public TimePickerDismissal(TimePicker timer)
    {
        timer.GotFocus += OnTimeGotFocus;
        timer.LostFocus += OnTimeLostFocus;
        timer.TimeChanged += OnTimeChanged;
    }

    private void OnTimeGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_active)
        {
            return;
        }

        _active = false;

        if (!_timeChanged)
        {
            Dismissed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        _timeChanged = false;
    }

    private void OnTimeLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selector = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement() as LoopingSelector;

        if (selector == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        _active = true;
    }

    private void OnTimeChanged(object sender, TimePickerValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _timeChanged = true;
    }
}
```

Here's how to use it:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var dismissal = new TimePickerDismissal(MyTimePicker);

        dismissal.Dismissed += OnTimerDismissed;
    }

    private void OnTimerDismissed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("TimePicker dismissed!");
    }
}
```

Give that a shot. Let me know if it works for you. You can probably turn this into a behavior actually...